# i want to show image in my notification and i tried to do that in extension notification service but it didnt work

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

```
override func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void) {

    self.contentHandler = contentHandler
    bestAttemptContent = (request.content.mutableCopy() as? UNMutableNotificationContent)
    
    if let bestAttemptContent = bestAttemptContent {

        if let attachmentString = bestAttemptContent.userInfo["url"] as? String,let attachmentURL = URL(string: attachmentString){
            let session = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)
            let dawnloadTask = session.downloadTask(with: attachmentURL, completionHandler:{ (url, _, error) in
                if let error = error{
                    print(error)
                }else if let url = url{
                    let attatchment = try! UNNotificationAttachment(identifier: attachmentString, url: url, options: [UNNotificationAttachmentOptionsTypeHintKey:kUnknownType])
                    bestAttemptContent.attachments=[attatchment]
                }
                contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
                })
            dawnloadTask.resume()
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: "data": {
      "name_ar": "",
      "id": "",
      "des": "",
      "url": "",
      "title": "",
      "body": "",
      "image": ""
    },
    "notification": {
      "title": "",
      "body": "",
      "image": "",
    },

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the image is sent in `https`.
Example: https://www.yoursite.com/image.jpg

Comment: The url is in this form

Comment: Make sure the push is sending in this format from server side. See image.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMnu0.jpg

Comment: iOS put the push in a comment below the question and I think it’s true

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in `NotificationService` class.

```
override func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void) {
        self.contentHandler = contentHandler
        bestAttemptContent = (request.content.mutableCopy() as? UNMutableNotificationContent)
        
        if let bestAttemptContent = bestAttemptContent {
            func failEarly() {
                contentHandler(request.content)
            }
            
            guard let attachmentURL = bestAttemptContent.userInfo["thumbnail"] as? String else {
                return failEarly()
            }
            
            guard let url = URL(string: attachmentURL) else {
                return failEarly()
            }
            
            do {
                let imageData = try Data(contentsOf: url)
                guard let attachment = UNNotificationAttachment.create(imageFileIdentifier: "image", data: imageData, options: nil) else {
                    return failEarly()
                }
                
                bestAttemptContent.attachments = [attachment]
                contentHandler(bestAttemptContent.copy() as! UNNotificationContent)
            }catch(let error) {
                return failEarly()
            }
        }
    }

extension UNNotificationAttachment {
    
    static func create(imageFileIdentifier: String, data: Data, options: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> UNNotificationAttachment? {
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let tmpSubFolderName = ProcessInfo.processInfo.globallyUniqueString
        let tmpSubFolderURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(tmpSubFolderName, isDirectory: true)
        
        do {
            try fileManager.createDirectory(at: tmpSubFolderURL!, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
            let fileURL = tmpSubFolderURL?.appendingPathComponent(imageFileIdentifier)
            try data.write(to: fileURL!, options: [])
            let imageAttachment = try UNNotificationAttachment.init(identifier: imageFileIdentifier, url: fileURL!, options: options)
            return imageAttachment
        } catch let error {
            print("error \(error)")
        }
        
        return nil
    }
}
```